# docker run python from container

Tags: docker

I took over a project which requires the usage of docker to setup the development environment. The project wiki is primarily written for use with coreos and one of the setup steps involved running a python script.

I'm using boot2docker and realised that there's no python pre-installed with the tcl. However, the image that I've pulled from the project repository comes with python27.

How do I use the python interpreter from the container in the VM without having to type `docker exec` every time?

Also, how do I access the project code in the boot2docker vm (not docker) instance locally so that I can do development on an IDE?

Comment: I've only messed around with docker, I haven't actually done much with it.  However, the workflow that I think is appropriate is to do your dev on your local system (i.e. your mac, not within the b2d vm).  and publish your code into a new container to actually run it.  (copy files to right place, docker build, docker run).

Answer (score 2):

You can mount your local directory to the container then run it almost as if it were on your local machine. For example:

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/app -w /app iron/python:2 python hello.py
```

That mounts your current directory and run hello.py from that directory.

You can find full examples of this here: https://github.com/iron-io/dockerworker/tree/master/python